# Select dropdown after low search form selected for custom channel field

Tags: expresso-store, low-search

```
<select name="store:price">
    <option value="0">PRICE</option>
    <option value="|10"{if low_search_store:price == "|10"} selected{/if}>up to $10</option>
    <option value="10|25"{if low_search_store:price == "10|25"} selected{/if}>$10 to $25</option>
    <option value="25|50"{if low_search_store:price == "25|50"} selected{/if}>$25 to $50</option>
    <option value="50|100"{if low_search_store:price == "50|100"} selected{/if}>$50 to $100</option>
    <option value="100|"{if low_search_store:price == "100|"} selected{/if}>$100 and up</option>
</select>
```

This works great, when the search form is submitted, it returns the results with the price select selected based on the query in segement 3.

I also want to be able to search based on color, that value is stored in the products channel custom field: cf_product_color and not as a store modifier.

```
<select name="search:cf_product_color">
    <option value="">COLOR</option>
    <option value="red" {if search:cf_product_color=="red"} selected{/if}>Red</option>
    <option value="orange" {if search:cf_product_color=="orange"} selected{/if}>Orange</option>
</select>
```

This does not work, when I select a color (I know the color exists in that custom field: cf_product_color for entries) and it does not select the color from the select color drop down after submitting like it does for the price select drop-down.

This leads me to think I need to create a collection since I have a price, color select dropdowns making it 2 pieces of data I am searching for. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to create collections if you're using [the Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords).

The variables created based on the parameters need to be **prefixed** with `low_search_`, as per [how params work in LS](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#params). So try this as a conditional instead:

```
{if low_search_search:cf_product_color == "red"}
```

Comment: what should the name of the select field be? select name="cf_product_color" ?

Comment: No, `name="search:field_name"`, see http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search

Comment: Got that part working now I notice it won't return any results unless I have both a value selected in the price and color drop-downs. If I leave the price blank/unselected and select a color, it returns nothing, if I select the price along with a color, it returns results. If I leave the color dropdown unselected/blank and select a price, it returns results. I need the ability to select one or both.

Comment: Your first Price option should have an empty value rather than 0: `<option value="">PRICE</option>` -- 0 is a valid value, too.